# Semanitc ui menu is displayed wrong

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I stared with semantic ui and I wanted a Menu on the top of the page, so I tried this code

```
  <body>
    <div class="ui menu green inverted">
        <h3 class="item">item1</h3>
        <a class=" item">item2</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

But the result istn't as I expected ;) 
[image]

Can somebody how to get the menu displayed correctly?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? Also, why is one of your items an h3?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample code in the semantic docs?

http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html

```
<div class="ui menu">
  <a class="item">Browse</a>
  <a class="item">Submit</a>
  <div class="right menu">
    <a class="item">Sign Up</a>
    <a class="item">Help</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you seem to have a header in the as one of the menu items, any particular reason for that?

Comment: Causes an similar result :/

Comment: @kedritsch are you sure your css links are resolving correctly?: http://jsbin.com/vizenohuva/1/edit?html,output works for me

Comment: The problem was caused by an other stylesheet I included ... :)